# How to resize body with webgrid?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-3

Q: How can I re-size body with the width of an mvc3 webgrid (it's a wide grid view where width=100%)?

[image]

CSS --

```
.webgrid   /* This works fine...stretches 100% with scrollbars at bottom of browser
{
    width: 100%;
}

body
{
    /* What can I put here for width: "Stretch the body the same % or length as the webgrid */
    /* width: 100% <- DOESN'T WORK!!! Grid still runs over body page! */
}
```

Razor (cshtml) --

```
<div  id="grid" class="gen">
    @grid.GetHtml(
        tableStyle: "webgrid",...)
```

Answer (score 0):

when you implement grid in view and set tablestyle in parameter like

```
        @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "grid",.............)
```

pick the name you give in tablestyle and use it as a class

```
<style type="text/css">
.grid{

   width:100px;
  }

</style>
```

i think it works

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.  That doesn't solve the issue.  See my edits in original post.  That is actually what I currently have implemented (100% width for webgrid).  The issue is the body is not re-sizing when the grid is wide (and when the grid is set to 100%).

Answer (score 0):

The table's cells can't be smaller than its contents.

Some solutions:

1. Consider to show some columns only on the details view;
2. Provide cells with a tooltip and try to reduce the text length;
3. Increase the width of the whole page.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

In Site.css, for the class webgrid-Style, change width to 100%.